# How to skip validation for last object in fieldArray form using yup validation schema with react-hook-form?

Tags: reactjs, validation, yup, react-hook-form

I have tried (required) validation with fieldsArray form i was able to do so but not i want to skip that validation for last index object of fieldArray.

Here's Schema i tried:

```
const schema= yup.object().shape({
field1: yup.string().required("Required."),
field2: yup.string().required("Required."),
MoreFields: yup.array().min(1, "Create at least one").of(
yup.object().shape({
f1: yup.string().required('Required'),
f2: yup.string().required('Required'),
}) ),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove last element before do validation

```js
 const schema= yup.object().shape({
     field1: yup.string().required("Required."),
     field2: yup.string().required("Required."),
     MoreFields: yup.array()
         .min(1, "Create at least one")
+        .transfrom(fields => fields.slice(1))
         .of(yup.object().shape({
             f1: yup.string().required('Required'),
             f2: yup.string().required('Required'),
         })),
     });
```

Doc: https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedtransformcurrentvalue-any-originalvalue-any--any-schema